# jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-187 Fabric ssh script Error - Command not found: function

Tags: redhat, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, fusefabric

1. Created a Fabric Root

started ./fuse and then executed bellow command

```
fabric:create --wait-for-provisioning --verbose --clean --new-user admin --new-user-role admin --new-user-password admin --zookeeper-password zoopassword --resolver manualip --manual-ip 127.0.0.1
```

2. Started another fuse server ./fuse with ssh listening on 8102
3. Executed bellow command in the root console(fuse running at step 1 as root)

   fabric:container-create-ssh  --host 127.0.0.1 --user admin --password admin --port 8102 --new-user admin --new-user-password admin --resolver manualip --manual-ip 127.0.0.1 mqgateway

Then getting this Error :

```
--- command ---
#!/bin/bash function run { echo "Running: $*" ; $* ; rc=$? ; if [ "${rc}" -ne 0 ]; then echo "Command Failed:Error running installation script: $*" ; exit ${rc} ; fi ; }

function sudo_n { SUDO_NON_INTERACTIVE=`sudo -h | grep "\-n"`   if [
-z "$SUDO_NON_INTERACTIVE" ]; then
     sudo $*   else
     sudo -n $*   fi }

function download {   echo "Downloading: $1";   ret=`curl -C - --retry 10 --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output $2 $1`;   if [ "${ret}"
-ne 200 ]; then
    echo "Download failed with code: ${ret}";
    rm $2;   fi; }

function maven_download {   echo "Downloading Maven Artifact with groupId: $2 artifactId: $3 and version: $4 from repository: $1";   export REPO=$1   export GROUP_ID=$2   export ARTIFACT_ID=$3   export VERSION=$4   export TYPE=$5   export TARGET_FILE=$ARTIFACT_ID-$VERSION.$TYPE

  export GROUP_ID_PATH=`echo $GROUP_ID | sed 's/\./\//g'`

  export ARTIFACT_BASE_URL=`echo $REPO$GROUP_ID_PATH/$ARTIFACT_ID/$VERSION/`

  if [[ "$VERSION" == *SNAPSHOT* ]];  then
    export ARTIFACT_URL=`curl --location -C - --retry 10 --silent $ARTIFACT_BASE_URL | grep href | grep zip\" | sed 's/^.*<a href="//' | sed 's/".*$//'  | tail -1`   else
    export ARTIFACT_URL=`echo $REPO$GROUP_ID_PATH/$ARTIFACT_ID/$VERSION/$ARTIFACT_ID-$VERSION.$TYPE` fi

  if [ -z "$ARTIFACT_URL" ]; then
      export ARTIFACT_URL=`echo $REPO$GROUP_ID_PATH/$ARTIFACT_ID/$VERSION/$ARTIFACT_ID-$VERSION.$TYPE` fi

  echo "Using URL: $ARTIFACT_URL"   ret=`curl --location --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output $TARGET_FILE $ARTIFACT_URL`   if [ "${ret}" -ne 200 ]; then
    echo "Download failed with code: ${ret}"
    rm $TARGET_FILE   fi }

function update_pkgs() {   if which dpkg &> /dev/null; then
    sudo_n apt-get update    elif which rpm &> /dev/null; then
        sudo_n yum check-update   fi }

function install_curl() {   echo "Checking if curl is present."   if which curl &> /dev/null; then
    echo "Curl is already installed."   else
    echo "Installing curl."
    if which dpkg &> /dev/null; then
      sudo_n apt-get -y install curl
    elif which rpm &> /dev/null; then
     sudo_n yum -y install curl
    fi   fi }

function install_unzip() {   echo "Checking if unzip is present."   if which unzip &> /dev/null; then
    echo "Unzip is already installed."   else
    echo "Installing unzip."
    if which dpkg &> /dev/null; then
      sudo_n apt-get -y install unzip
    elif which rpm &> /dev/null; then
     sudo_n yum -y install unzip
    fi   fi }

function install_openjdk_deb() {   sudo_n apt-get -y install openjdk-7-jdk

  # Try to set JAVA_HOME in a number of commonly used locations   # Lifting JAVA_HOME detection from jclouds
      for CANDIDATE in `ls -d /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-* /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-* /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk 2>&-`; do
          if [ -n "$CANDIDATE" -a -x "$CANDIDATE/bin/java" ]; then
              export JAVA_HOME=$CANDIDATE
              break
          fi
      done

  if [ -f /etc/profile ]; then
    sudo_n "echo 'export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME' >> /etc/profile"   fi   if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    sudo_n "echo 'export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME' >> /etc/bashrc"   fi   if [ -f ~root/.bashrc ]; then
    sudo_n "echo 'export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME' >> ~root/.bashrc"   fi   if [ -f /etc/skel/.bashrc ]; then
    sudo_n "echo 'export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME' >> /etc/skel/.bashrc"   fi   if [ -f "$DEFAULT_HOME/$NEW_USER" ]; then
    sudo_n "echo 'export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME' >> $DEFAULT_HOME/$NEW_USER"   fi

  sudo_n update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java $JAVA_HOME/bin/java 17000   sudo_n update-alternatives --set java $JAVA_HOME/bin/java   java -version }

function install_openjdk_rpm() {   sudo_n yum -y install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel

  # Try to set JAVA_HOME in a number of commonly used locations   # Lifting JAVA_HOME detection from jclouds
      for CANDIDATE in `ls -d /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-* /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-* /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk 2>&-`; do
          if [ -n "$CANDIDATE" -a -x "$CANDIDATE/bin/java" ]; then
              export JAVA_HOME=$CANDIDATE
              break
          fi
      done

  if [ -f /etc/profile ]; then
    sudo_n "echo 'export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME' >> /etc/profile"   fi   if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    sudo_n "echo 'export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME' >> /etc/bashrc"   fi   if [ -f ~root/.bashrc ]; then
    sudo_n "echo 'export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME' >> ~root/.bashrc"   fi   if [ -f /etc/skel/.bashrc ]; then
    sudo_n "echo 'export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME' >> /etc/skel/.bashrc"   fi   if [ -f "$DEFAULT_HOME/$NEW_USER" ]; then
    sudo_n "echo 'export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME' >> $DEFAULT_HOME/$NEW_USER"   fi

  sudo_n alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java $JAVA_HOME/bin/java 17000   sudo_n alternatives --set java $JAVA_HOME/bin/java   java
-version }

function install_openjdk() {
    echo "Checking if java is present."
    ARCH=`uname -m`
    JAVA_VERSION=`java -version 2>&1`
    if [[ $JAVA_VERSION == *1.7* ]]; then
     echo "Java is already installed."
    else
      echo "Installing java."
      if which dpkg &> /dev/null; then
        install_openjdk_deb
      elif which rpm &> /dev/null; then
        install_openjdk_rpm
      fi
    fi }

function validate_requirements() {   if ! which curl &> /dev/null; then
    echo "Command Failed:Curl is not installed.";   fi   if ! which java &> /dev/null; then
      echo "Command Failed:Java is not installed.";
      exit -1;   else
    check_java_version   fi }

function check_java_version() {   JAVA_VERSION=`java -version 2>&1 | grep "[java|openjdk] version" | awk '{print $3}' | tr -d \" | awk '{split($0, array, ".")} END{print array[2]}'`   if [ $JAVA_VERSION
-ge 6 ]; then
    echo "Java version is greater than 1.6."   else
    echo "Command Failed:Unsupported java version: 1.$JAVA_VERSION.x found."
    exit -1;   fi }

function exit_if_not_exists() {  if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
          echo "Command Failed:Could not find file $1";
          exit -1;  fi  local zipFile="$1"  local size="$(du $zipFile |  awk '{ print $1}')"  if [ $size -lt 100 ]; then
          echo "Command Failed: Zip archive is empty. Check $1";
          exit -1;  fi

}

function copy_node_metadata() {   echo "Copying metadata for container: $1";   TARGET_PATH="./fabric/import/fabric/registry/containers/config/$1/"   mkdir -p $TARGET_PATH   ENCODED_METADATA=$2   echo $ENCODED_METADATA > ./fabric/import/fabric/registry/containers/config/$1/metadata.cfg }

function karaf_check() {    KARAF_HOME=$1    INSTANCES_FILE=$KARAF_HOME/instances/instance.properties    for i in {1..5};
     do
       if [ ! -f $INSTANCES_FILE ]; then
         sleep 1
       else
         break
       fi
     done    if [ -f $INSTANCES_FILE ]; then
      for j in {1..5};
         do
           PID=`cat $INSTANCES_FILE | grep "item.0.pid" | awk -F "=" '{print $2}'`
           if [ "$PID" = "" ]; then
             sleep 1
           else
            break
           fi
     done
     if ps -p $PID > /dev/null; then
       echo "Fabric is started successfully"
     else
       echo "Command Failed: Karaf process ($PID) is not running"
     fi    else
     echo "Command Failed:Could not find Karaf instance.properties"    fi }

function replace_in_file {   sed "s/$1/$2/g" $3 > $3.tmp   rm $3   mv $3.tmp $3 }

function replace_property_value {   echo "Setting value $2 for key $1 in $3"   sed "s/$1[ \t]*=.*/$1 = $2/g" $3 > $3.tmp   rm $3   mv $3.tmp $3 }

function configure_hostnames() {   CLOUD_PROVIDER=$1   case $CLOUD_PROVIDER in
    openstack-nova | ec2 | aws-ec2 )
      echo "Resolving public hostname for ec2 node"
      export PUBLIC_HOSTNAME=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname | sed 's/ /_/g'`
      echo PUBLIC_HOSTNAME
    ;;
    cloudservers | cloudservers-uk | cloudservers-us )
      echo "Resovling public hostname for rackspace node"
      PRIVATE_IP=`/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'`
      export PUBLIC_HOSTNAME=`echo $PRIVATE_IP | tr . -`.static.cloud-ips.com
    ;;   esac    if [ ! -z ${PUBLIC_HOSTNAME} ]; then
        LOOKUP_ADDRESS=`nslookup $PUBLIC_HOSTNAME > /dev/null | grep Address | tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 3 | sed 's/ /_/g'`
        echo "Found hostname: $PUBLIC_HOSTNAME matching with address: $LOOKUP_ADDRESS"
        echo "publichostname=$PUBLIC_HOSTNAME" >> etc/system.properties
        cat etc/system.properties | grep -v 'local.resolver=' | grep -v 'global.resolver=' > etc/system.properties.tmp
        mv etc/system.properties.tmp etc/system.properties
        echo "local.resolver=publichostname" >> etc/system.properties
        echo "global.resolver=publichostname" >> etc/system.properties
        echo $PUBLIC_HOSTNAME > hostname
        sudo_n cp hostname /etc/
        export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$PUBLIC_HOSTNAME $JAVA_OPTS"
        echo "RESOLVER OVERRIDE:publichostname"    fi }

function find_free_port() {    START_PORT=$1    END_PORT=$2    for port in `eval echo {$START_PORT..$END_PORT}`;do
        if [[ $OSTYPE == darwin* ]]; then
                # macosx has a different syntax for netstat
                netstat -atp tcp | tr -s ' ' ' '| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | grep ":$port" > /dev/null 2>&1 && continue || echo $port && break;
        else
                netstat -utan | tr -s ' ' ' '| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | grep ":$port" > /dev/null 2>&1 && continue || echo $port && break;
        fi    done }

function wait_for_port() {
    PORT=$1
    for i in {1..5};
        do
                        if [[ $OSTYPE == darwin* ]]; then
                                # macosx has a different syntax for netstat
                                netstat -an -ptcp | grep LISTEN | tr -s ' ' ' '| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | grep ":$PORT" > /dev/null 2>&1 && break;
                        else
                                netstat -lnt | tr -s ' ' ' '| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | grep ":$PORT" > /dev/null 2>&1 && break;
                        fi
                        sleep 5;
        done
        return 0 }

function extract_zip {   if ! which unzip &> /dev/null; then
        jar xf $1   else
       unzip -o $1   fi }

function generate_ssh_keys {   if [ ! -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa ]; then
        mkdir -p ~/.ssh
        ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa   fi }

run mkdir -p ~/containers/ run cd ~/containers/ run mkdir -p mqgateway run cd mqgateway validate_requirements cp /tmp/fabric8-karaf-1.2.0.redhat-630187.zip fabric8-karaf-1.2.0.redhat-630187.zip if ! jar xf fabric8-karaf-1.2.0.redhat-630187.zip &> /dev/null; then rm fabric8-karaf-1.2.0.redhat-630187.zip ; fi if [ ! -f fabric8-karaf-1.2.0.redhat-630187.zip ] && [ ! -s fabric8-karaf-1.2.0.redhat-630187.zip ] ; then maven_download http://127.0.0.1:8181/maven/download/ io.fabric8 fabric8-karaf
1.2.0.redhat-630187 zip exit_if_not_exists fabric8-karaf-1.2.0.redhat-630187.zip run extract_zip fabric8-karaf-1.2.0.redhat-630187.zip run cd `ls -l | grep fabric8-karaf | grep ^d | awk '{ print $NF }' | sort -n | head -1` run mkdir -p system/io/fabric8/fabric8-karaf/1.2.0.redhat-630187 run cp ../fabric8-karaf-1.2.0.redhat-630187.zip system/io/fabric8/fabric8-karaf/1.2.0.redhat-630187/ run rm ../fabric8-karaf-1.2.0.redhat-630187.zip run chmod +x bin/* cat >> etc/system.properties <<'END_OF_FILE' global.resolver=localhostname END_OF_FILE replace_property_value "karaf.name" "mqgateway" etc/system.properties replace_property_value "importDir" "fabric" etc/io.fabric8.datastore.cfg replace_property_value "felix.fileinstall.filename" "file:\/C:\/Fabric\/root\/etc\/io.fabric8.datastore.cfg" etc/io.fabric8.datastore.cfg replace_property_value "component.name" "io.fabric8.datastore" etc/io.fabric8.datastore.cfg replace_property_value "gitRemotePollInterval" "60000" etc/io.fabric8.datastore.cfg replace_property_value "service.pid" "io.fabric8.datastore" etc/io.fabric8.datastore.cfg BIND_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0 SSH_PORT="`find_free_port 8101 65535`" RMI_REGISTRY_PORT="`find_free_port 1099 65535`" RMI_SERVER_PORT="`find_free_port 44444 65535`" JMX_SERVER_URL="service:jmx:rmi:\/\/${BIND_ADDRESS}:${RMI_SERVER_PORT}\/jndi\/rmi:\/\/${BIND_ADDRESS}:${RMI_REGISTRY_PORT}\/karaf-mqgateway" HTTP_PORT="`find_free_port 8181 65535`" replace_property_value "sshPort" "$SSH_PORT" etc/org.apache.karaf.shell.cfg replace_property_value "sshHost" "$BIND_ADDRESS" etc/org.apache.karaf.shell.cfg replace_property_value "rmiRegistryPort" "$RMI_REGISTRY_PORT" etc/org.apache.karaf.management.cfg replace_property_value "rmiServerPort" "$RMI_SERVER_PORT" etc/org.apache.karaf.management.cfg replace_property_value "rmiServerHost" "$BIND_ADDRESS" etc/org.apache.karaf.management.cfg replace_property_value "rmiRegistryHost" "$BIND_ADDRESS" etc/org.apache.karaf.management.cfg replace_property_value "org.osgi.service.http.port" "$HTTP_PORT" etc/org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg replace_in_file "8181" "$HTTP_PORT" etc/jetty.xml cat >> etc/system.properties <<'END_OF_FILE' minimum.port=0 END_OF_FILE cat >> etc/system.properties <<'END_OF_FILE' maximum.port=65535 END_OF_FILE cat >> etc/system.properties <<'END_OF_FILE'


END_OF_FILE cat >> etc/system.properties <<'END_OF_FILE' preferred.network.address=127.0.0.1 END_OF_FILE cat >> etc/system.properties <<'END_OF_FILE' zookeeper.url = 127.0.0.1:2181 END_OF_FILE cat >> etc/system.properties <<'END_OF_FILE' zookeeper.password = ZKENC=em9vcGFzc3dvcmQ= END_OF_FILE cat >> etc/system.properties <<'END_OF_FILE' zookeeper.password.encode = true END_OF_FILE cat >> etc/system.properties <<'END_OF_FILE' agent.auto.start=true END_OF_FILE sed  's/featuresBoot=/&fabric-agent,fabric-git,/' etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg > etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg.tmp mv etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg.tmp etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg sed  's/repositories=/&http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8181\/maven\/download\/,/' etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg > etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg.tmp mv etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg.tmp etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg generate_ssh_keys configure_hostnames none cat > bin/setenv <<'END_OF_FILE' export JAVA_OPTS=" -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:+UnsyncloadClass -server"

END_OF_FILE nohup bin/start & karaf_check `pwd` wait_for_port $SSH_PORT wait_for_port $RMI_REGISTRY_PORT

--- output --- Command not found: function

--- error ---

------
```

Comment: Could you provide some more information regarding your setup?

Comment: I tried to create a fuse server as fabric root in windows 7 then i am trying to connect to another Jboss fuse server running on windows 7 through SSH but every time its gives the error like this Error : Command not found: function.

Comment: I don't think that having a Fuse Server on Windows 7 is a good idea - its not supported https://access.redhat.com/articles/310603

Comment: thanks for answering please find the exact error above in the question. is it because of windows 7.

Comment: This script expects a *nix Operating System with `bash` (see `#!/bin/bash`) to be present. Which of course is not available under Windows 7.

Comment: Did the same thing with a linux setup . same issue

Comment: Strange. Do you have more information regarding your setup? How did you install it on linux?

Comment: Found the solution ssh was not installed in other server. i used openssh and its working right now. thanks

Comment: Even a linux server without ssh?

Comment: Actually i was trying to connect a fuse instance and karaf gogo shell cant able to execute the create container script. now i removed that instance and installed a ssh server in the remote system and root fabric is creating the container files there by executing the script in the powershell

Comment: And if using fuse fabric in windows please use fabric:join not ssh. ssh will not work because of windows limitation

Answer (score 0):

SSH containers should be created on Remote machines.An SSH container is just a Fabric container that is running on a remote host on your local network,
where that host is accessible through the SSH protocol. This section describes some basic administration tasks for these SSH containers.

Please refer https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/fabric_guide/chapter-fabric_container#ContSSH

If you want to create containers on the same machine (local host) create child containers
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/fabric_guide/chapter-fabric_container#ContChild

Answer (score 0):

Creating ssh container

```
fabric:container-create-ssh --host remotehost --user user1 --password pass1  --jvm-opts="-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=remotehost" --profile fabric fabric-eu03
```