# Karaf Shell : command not found function

Tags: bash, shell, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

function test{ echo "hello";} is not able to execute in karaf shell.

Error : **Command not found: function**

Comment: Where did you discover this idea of functions in the shell?
Karaf is telling you that the gogo shell doesn't understand the idea.
There is no 'function' command.

Comment: I am using Jboss fuse facing this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803936/jboss-fuse-6-3-0-redhat-187-fabric-ssh-script-error-command-not-found-functio

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Apache Karaf but I do know that the `function` syntax that you have used is non-standard. It is supported by Bash but not all other shells.

The standard function syntax in the shell is simply:

```
test() { echo "hello"; }
```

I would suggest using it everywhere.